# Quickly switch between multiple terminals

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode 1.23.0

I often use multiple terminals inside of VSCode. If I have to switch between those terminals. I have to move the mouse and click on the drop down and then select the terminal which I need to go to. This is very painful and slow.

I wonder if there is a shortcut to quickly switch between terminals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are the two commands:

```
{
  "key": "",    
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext"
}
```

and

```
{
  "key": "",    
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious"
}
```

They are currently unassigned to a keybinding.

And there are the available commands:

```
workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex1
```

etc. (1-9) which allow you to go directly to that terminal number.

Comment: You can open the "Keyboard Shortcuts" from the gear icon in the lower left and then search for "terminal" to see the terminal-related commands.  Click on the "+" to create your keybinding.